# I have been trying to zip two files together and it worked exept when one is too short it only zips until it reaches the end of the short variable

Tags: list, variables, zip

output3 = [x + y for x, y in zip(output1, output2)]

if O1L == O2L:

```
output3 = [x + y for x, y in zip(output1, output2)]
```

elif O2L > O1L:

I dont know what to do here